# IIS Application Initialization module sending request to localhost

Tags: wcf, iis, msmq

I have a WCF Service using MSMQ, hosted in IIS. The service doesn't fire up and read messages from the queue until the URL to the service's SVC page has been hit in a browser, which is problem after deployment and the app pool recycling. To resolve this I installed the [IIS Application Initialization module](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationInitialization) which will send a fake request to a page specified in the Web.config like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <applicationInitialization remapManagedRequestsTo="Startup.htm" skipManagedModules="true" >
    <add initializationPage="/MyService.svc" />
  </applicationInitialization>
</system.webServer>
```

The problem I'm having is that it's hitting localhost when my site is bound to another domain, so I'm seeing this error:

> WebHost failed to process a request.  Sender Information:
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/42715336 
>   Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: No protocol
>   binding matches the given address 'http://localhost/MyService.svc'.
>   Protocol bindings are configured at the Site level in IIS or WAS
>   configuration. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No protocol
>   binding matches the given address 'http://localhost/MyService.svc'.
>   Protocol bindings are configured at the Site level in IIS or WAS
>   configuration.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: Don't host a MSMQ endpoint in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with an SVN Service Connecting to an EMS Server so it should work.  If it doesn't create an ASPX page that does something like the followign that can even exercise your service.

```
<%@ Page aspcompat=true Language="VBScript"  %>


Dim objSvrHTTP
Dim PostData
Dim WebName
Dim SoapAction
    SoapAction = "Your Soap Action"

WebName = Request.URL.Host & ":" & Request.URL.Port


 objSvrHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
 PostData = "Soap Post XML (Recoreded probably)"

objSvrHTTP.open("POST", "http://" & WebName & "/path/SVCFile.svc", false)
objSvrHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml" )
' set SOAPAction as appropriate for the operation '
 objSvrHTTP.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", SoapAction )

objSvrHTTP.Send(cstr(PostData))

dim serviceResponse
dim ExpectedResponse 
    ExpectedResponse = "asdf"
serviceResponse = objSvrHTTP.responseText 

if (serviceResponse <> ExpectedResponse) then
    Response.Write("The Service Didn't return false and should have.  it returned: " )
    Response.Write(serviceResponse)
else
    Response.Write("OK")
end if
```